# Run maven commands from java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, artifact, maven-invoker-plugin

I need to run maven commands from the Spring-boot application directed at another spring-boot application.

I am trying to use maven-invoker but it is requiring setMavenHome. Can I download maven as an artifact instead of giving access to my maven directly?

Comment: What Maven commands do you want to run? For what purpose?

Comment: You can set whatever variables you want, including a different local repository

Comment: Trying to run mvn clean install to build a different project based on parameters submitted to the current project

Comment: @incareofvarx Are you sure you want to do this in Spring Boot? This looks like a job for Jenkins (or any other build server).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid using the Jenkins pipeline and do the build locally. It is a custom case that needs to run locally